# match text in a csv file, for the X firsts lines and the last X results and get a value in lua

Tags: csv, filter, lua, grep

i'm translating a bash script to a Lua program. In bash script there is a line:

```
mapfile -t vol < <( cat csv_file | head -$id | grep locateme | tail -3 | cut -f6 -d\,)
```

the result of that is:

```
vol[0]=22
vol[1]=33
vol[2]=44
```

the csv_file is like:

```
16,a,b,c,d,9,16,0,3,65,0,0,locateme
16,a,b,c,d,11,16,0,3,65,0,0,notme
16,a,b,c,d,22,16,0,3,65,0,0,locateme
16,a,b,c,d,33,16,0,3,65,0,0,locateme
16,a,b,c,d,32,16,0,3,65,0,0,notme
16,a,b,c,d,44,16,0,3,65,0,0,locateme
```

I need a table with the same results than bash:

```
vol[1]=22
vol[2]=33
vol[3]=44
```

please, i have no idea how to start with this

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21176388/3832970) help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Bash array you're going to use a Lua table.

```
local vol = {}
```

You'll need a [generic for loop](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.5) and the [file:lines(...)](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-file:lines) iterator. It is a good idea to read through the whole [io library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.8).

This will allow you to get each line of the csv file as a string for further processing.

No you'll need [Lua's string library](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4). There are multiple ways to do this. One option is to use another generic for loop with string.gmatch and a suitable string pattern that captures the value you're interested in.